# Какова вероятность того, что команда A выиграет в 3 из 5 матчей?

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Есть две команды A и B. Вероятность того, что команда A выиграет в одной игре - 55%, вероятность того, что команда B выиграет в одной игре - 45%. (команды играют друг против друга)

Какова вероятность того, что команда A выиграет в 3 из 5 матчей (в 2 из 5/ в 2 из 4)

Как это считается ?

Comment: Это вопрос по математике, а не по программированию.

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача на схему Бернулли:

> Теорема Бернулли:
>
> Если вероятность p наступления события A в каждом испытании постоянна,
>   то вероятность P<sub>k,n</sub> того, что событие A наступит ровно k
>   раз в n независимых испытаниях, равна  :
>   P<sub>k,n</sub> = C<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>p<sup>k</sup>q<sup>n-k</sup>
>
> где q=1-p

Применим схему к нашей задаче:

**Дано:**

```
Количество испытаний --- n = 5
Количество наступления события --- k = 3
Вероятность наступления события --- p = 0.55
q = 1 - p = 0.45
```

**Решение:**

P<sub>3,5</sub> = C<sub>5</sub><sup>3</sup>0.55<sup>3</sup>0.45<sup>5-3</sup> = 10 * 0,166375 * 0,2025 = 0,336909375 ≈ 0.34

Да простят меня участники сообщества за ответ на вопрос не по теме.